# hlk-m30 WebClient example

Tags: atmega, embedded, wifi, at-commands

I have started working on [HLK-m30](http://hacktronics.co.in/home/895-hlk-m30-embedded-uart-to-ethernet-wifi-module.html) WiFi module. I am developing the simple client on the module using simple AT commands. I have Opened socket TCP client and then Write data using the command.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

when I read socket using AT command it shows me 0:ok. whereas 0 is Socket number and ok is response of command but not receiving any data.
Also I am not able to make it work on transparent transmission mode.
when I am reading Socket query, Using at+SL command. I got this:

```
at+SL=?
0:2,3
1:0,0
2:0,0
3:0,0
```

If anyone here as worked on this module please guide me.

**EDIT1:**

I have written a code on ATmega16 which open socket, write to it and receive or read socket.
I am sending http get request to a server but not able to receive the response back. What can be the problem?
here is my code:

```
/*
 * ATmega16_HLK_m30.c
 *
 * Created: 03-03-2015 16:12:22
 *  Author: B2
 */ 


#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL // or whatever may be your frequency
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <avr/eeprom.h>
#include "usart.h"
#include "dbg_putchar.h"

char buffer[255];
const char AT[]="at";                                                           
const char AT_WC[] = "at+WC=";                                                  //Calculation PMK
const char AT_DHCP[] = "at+dhcp=";                                              //Set DHCP or static IP
const char AT_UTYPE[] = "at+UType=";                                            //Set TCP or UDP
const char AT_UIP[] = "at+UIp=";                                                //Set remote IP address
const char AT_URPORT[] = "at+URPort=";                                          //Set remote port
const char AT_ULPORT[] = "at+ULPort=";                                          //Set local port
const char AT_REBOOT[] = "at+Rb=";                                              //Reboot module
const char AT_VERSION[] = "at+ver=";                                            //Get version
const char AT_DEFAULT[] = "at+Df=";                                             //Back to default settings
const char AT_SO[] = "at+SO=";                                                  //Socket open
const char AT_SC[] = "at+SC=";                                                  //Socket close
const char AT_SL[] = "at+SL=";                                                  //Socket check
const char AT_SW[] = "at+SW=";                                                  //Socket write
const char AT_SR[] = "at+SR=";                                                  //Socket read
const char AT_DR[] = "at+DR=";                                                  //Domain name resolution
const char AT_GPW[] = "at+GW=";                                                 //GPIO write
const char AT_GPR[] = "at+GR=";                                                 //GPIO read
const char AT_TS[] = "at+TS=";                                                  //Transparent transmission change
const char AT_MAC[] = "at+mac=";
char HttpRequest[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n";
uint8_t hlkM30SendCmd(char *,char *);   //Send Command
uint8_t hlkM30AT();                     //send at and check connection
uint8_t hlkM30_Dhcp();                  //Configure module with dynamic IP
uint8_t hlkM30TCPClient();              //Set TCP Client
uint8_t hlkM30LocalPort();              //Set local Port
uint8_t hlkM30RemotePort();             //Set Remote Port
uint8_t hlkM30PMK();                    //Calculate PMK
uint8_t hlkM30Reboot();                 //Reboot
uint8_t hlkM30OpenSocket();             //Open Socket
uint8_t hlkM30ListSocket();             //List Socket
uint8_t hlkM30WriteSocket();            //Write Socket
uint8_t hlkM30ReadSocket();             //Read  Socket
uint8_t hlkM30CloseSocket();            //Close Socket

int main(void)
{

    USARTInit(9600);
    dbg_tx_init();
    dbg_puts("HLK-M30 Test\r\n");
    //hlkM30Init();
    hlkM30AT();
    hlkM30_Dhcp();
    hlkM30TCPClient();
    hlkM30LocalPort();
    hlkM30RemotePort();
    //hlkM30CloseSocket();
    //hlkM30OpenSocket();
    hlkM30ListSocket();
    hlkM30WriteSocket();
    hlkM30ReadSocket();
    //hlkM30PMK();*/
}

uint8_t hlkM30SendCmd(char *cmd,char *val)
{
    UWriteString(cmd);
    UWriteString(val);
    UWriteData(0x0D);
}

uint8_t hlkM30AT()
{
        uint8_t len=0;
        uint16_t i=0;
        len=strlen(AT);
        UFlushBuffer();
        hlkM30SendCmd(AT,"\r");
        //UWriteString(AT);
        //Wait for echo
        _delay_ms(300);
        while(i<10*len)
        {
            if(UDataAvailable()<len)
            {
                i++;
                //dbg_putchar('.');
                _delay_ms(10);

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                //We got an echo
                //Now check it
                UReadBuffer(buffer,len);    //Read serial Dat
                //UWriteString(buffer);
                dbg_puts(buffer);
            }
        }
}

uint8_t hlkM30_Dhcp()
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_DHCP);
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_DHCP,"1\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<10*len)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,len);    //Read serial Dat
            //UWriteString(buffer);
            dbg_puts(buffer);
        }
    }
}

uint8_t hlkM30TCPClient()
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_UTYPE);
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_UTYPE,"2\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<10*len)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,10); //Read serial Dat
            //UWriteString(buffer);
            dbg_puts(buffer);
        }
    }
}

uint8_t hlkM30LocalPort()
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_ULPORT);
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_ULPORT,"80\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<10*len)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,17); //Read serial Dat
            //UWriteString(buffer);
            dbg_puts(buffer);
        }
    }
}

uint8_t hlkM30RemotePort()
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_URPORT);
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_URPORT,"80\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<10*len)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,19); //Read serial Dat
            //UWriteString(buffer);
            dbg_puts(buffer);
        }
    }
}

uint8_t hlkM30PMK()
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_WC);
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_WC,"1\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<10*len)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,7);  //Read serial Dat
            //UWriteString(buffer);
            dbg_puts(buffer);
        }
    }
}

uint8_t hlkM30OpenSocket()
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_SO);
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_SO,"2,www.stealmylogin.com,80,80\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<10*len)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,25); //Read serial Dat
            //UWriteString(buffer);
            dbg_puts(buffer);

        }
    }
}

uint8_t hlkM30ListSocket()
{
        uint8_t len=0;
        uint16_t i=0;
        len=strlen(AT_SL);
        UFlushBuffer();
        hlkM30SendCmd(AT_SL,"?\r");
        //Wait for echo
        _delay_ms(300);
        while(i<10*len)
        {
            if(UDataAvailable()<len)
            {
                i++;
                //dbg_putchar('.');
                _delay_ms(10);

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                //We got an echo
                //Now check it
                UReadBuffer(buffer,20); //Read serial Dat
                //UWriteString(buffer);
                dbg_puts(buffer);
            }
        }
}

uint8_t hlkM30CloseSocket()     //Close Socket
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_SC);
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_SC,"0\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<10*len)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,7);  //Read serial Dat
            //UWriteString(buffer);
            dbg_puts(buffer);
        }
    }
}

uint8_t hlkM30WriteSocket()
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_SW);
    //char str[];
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_SW,"0,,\"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.stealmylogin.com\r\n\r\n\"\r");
    //hlkM30SendCmd(AT_SW,"0,,\"GET / HTTP/1.1\n\r\"\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<1000)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,50); //Read serial Data
            dbg_puts(buffer);
        }
    }
}

uint8_t hlkM30ReadSocket()              //Read  Socket
{
    uint8_t len=0;
    uint16_t i=0;
    len=strlen(AT_SR);
    //char str[];
    UFlushBuffer();
    hlkM30SendCmd(AT_SR,"0,50\r");
    //hlkM30SendCmd(AT_SW,"0,,\"GET / HTTP/1.1\n\r\"\r");
    //Wait for echo
    _delay_ms(300);
    while(i<10*len)
    {
        if(UDataAvailable()<len)
        {
            i++;
            //dbg_putchar('.');
            _delay_ms(10);

            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //We got an echo
            //Now check it
            UReadBuffer(buffer,50); //Read serial Dat
            //UWriteString(buffer);
            dbg_puts(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the Log which I received:

```
HLK-M30 Test
at


at+dhcp=1
ok

at+UType=2
ok


at+ULPort=80
at+URPort=80
ok

at+SL=?
0:2,3
1:0,0
2:0,0
3:0,0


at+SW=0,,"GET / HTTP/1.1
ok
almylogin.com







ok
at+SR=0,50
0:ok
```

I dont understand what to do the next step?
How can I send receive from server?

Comment: need motivation guys.

Comment: Hi there?Need to develope a TCP client on HLK-m30 with ATmega16 micro controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Has been solved.
the configuration was correct. After reset the module, it gets connect to server and start send/receive data.